# CoreException: Could not calculate build plan; Maven on Eclipse 4.5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to get Maven working in my Eclipse at work, but I've encountered several problems and I don't know how to deal with them.

1) In Eclipse Marketplace i have following things installed in relation with Maven:
-Java 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2
- Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna and newer)

2). When I tried to convert my java project into Maven I got following errors:

```
- CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or 
 one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
 compiler-plugin:jar:3.3: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
 compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
 3.3:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
- CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or 
 one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
 compiler-plugin:jar:3.3: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
 plugin:pom:3.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
 reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
 artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/
 maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
 3.3:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
```

3) After that, following some responses here and there about the similar problems, I've changed my network options to "Native", but it didn't help.

4) I've tried locating "settings.xml" for Maven in the Eclipse folder, but there is none.

5) My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Kobiety_do_kodu</groupId>
  <artifactId>Kobiety_do_kodu</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Kobiety_do_kodu</name>
  <description>Introductory project from web</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

So it seems that although it's marked as installed in the Eclipse Marketplace, there is nothing beneath it?

Can you help me get it running?

Comment: From the error message: "Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
 plugin:pom:3.3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2". Do you have any proxy in your network? Have you configured it? The settings.xml file is in the config folder of maven, and in your ~/.m2 folder.

Comment: Yes, I'm working in an office network which sits behind a proxy, but I don't have all administrative privileges, so I don't know if I can configure it in any way.

And where the maven is installed by default when it's being installed from within Eclipse marketplace?

Comment: Then I would suggest you get the proxy information of your network then add them to your settings.xml, admin rights are not needed. Otherwise in settings.xml I'd try and point to the http central repo and give it a try